# Cordova / Phonegap inject javascript return value 3.4.0

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am creating a cordova / phonegap app using cordova 3.0.4

I am trying to use the inject javascript function to insert a function then get the return value. But nothing shows up in the alert box. this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>InAppBrowser.executeScript Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Global InAppBrowser reference
var iabRef = null;

// Inject our custom JavaScript into the InAppBrowser window
//
function addFeebackFunction() {
    iabRef.executeScript(
        {code: "var evaluateFeedback = function(){return 'Done';};"},
        function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
    //iabRef.close();
}

function iabClose(event) {
     iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', addFeebackFunction);
     iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
}

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
     iabRef = window.open('http://{ipaddress}/test/', '_blank', 'location=no');
     iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', addFeebackFunction);
     iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Mobile App</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I it returns an array of length 1, but when i alert the value of data[1] it is a value of null.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Then again, this guys seems to have got it working: http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova%27s-inappbrowser

Answer (score 0):

you're saying that it returns an array of length of 1, so data[1] is absolutely null, as arrays keys start with zero, so try 
data[0].